# Name does not exist in the current context ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to bind a value from an input type text to the gridview but I keep having errors "CS0103: The name 'dateborrowedTextBox' does not exist in the current context"

```
Date borrowed:
            <%--<asp:TextBox ID="dateborrowedTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("dateborrowed") %>' />--%>

            <%--date picker --%>
            <input type="text" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("dateborrowed") %>' name="dateborrowedTextBox" readonly="readonly" id="dateborrowedTextBox" /> 
            <a href="#" onclick="cdp1.showCalendar(this, '<%= dateborrowed.ClientID %>'); return false;">Date Picker</a>       
            <br />
```

So how can I declare it inside my date picker?

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to add the ClientID of your textbox to the showCalendar-js-function? Then you should also change `'<%= dateborrowed.ClientID %>'` to `'<%= dateborrowedTextBox.ClientID %>'`. Commented because that is not exactly the problem you asked for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your TextBox is commented out - change

```
<%--<asp:TextBox ID="dateborrowedTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("dateborrowed") %>' />--%>
```

to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dateborrowedTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("dateborrowed")%>' />
```

Comment: There is another input type="text" below the asp.net Textbox with this ID.

Comment: thanks but I still have the same error. Looks like I have to declare it inside the date picker. Also sorry forgot to remove the comments before posting my bad..

Comment: @Tim: Ah thanks yeah thats why I have to comment the TextBox control. Still it can't find the control. Anyway I'll try it again..